# Tomcat not redirect to form and shows blank page

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have developed a web application which is hosted locally using tomcat server when I submit any form tomcat shows blank page though the form data get saved in table i.e tomcat not redirect to form.

Comment: can you post you code

Comment: code is correct, when i run my application via ide then it'll runs fine but after deployment this problem occurs

Comment: do you get any error in tomcat console

Comment: browser shows error http/1.1 404 not found error

Comment: i can suggest you to use the latest version of Apache tomcat and web browser

Comment: i can check on  tomcat 7 and tomcat 8